# Alert message component variants

Tags: accessibility, component, design-system

I work in an e-commerce platform and we recently had a lively discussion about the variations of our alert message.

Would you agree that it is useful to have different versions of an alert or would you say that it is inconsistent to have multiple variations.

**Use case 1**

- Warning message on gray background, with a strong border to provide sufficient contrast with the background. (Better accessibility)
- 14px on smaller screens, 16px on large screens.

**Use case 2**

- Warning on top of page content. Without border (background color has enough contrast)
- 14px on smaller screens, 16px on large screens

**Use case 3**

- Alert inside product and other cards. Without border (background color has enough contrast).
- 12px on smaller screens, 14px on large screens.

Use case 1 or 2 can appear together with use case 3.

**Wdyt should the alert for consistency have always a border?**
I don't think so, since we don't want to have too much attention for use case 2 and 3, as the contrast on the white background is sufficient.
I think it makes sense to have a visual hierarchy for the alert message. The large version is on top of the page content and the small version for secondary information inside cards.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Would you be able to show us screen shots? I think I understand the concepts, but it would be helpful to see Use Case 3 in particular. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your question - i added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in branding.

Having the company logo in a color that works on a white background but presents little contrast on an alternative color background:

[image]

If the solution is to modify the style of the logo by adding a stroke, as the question says, the branding is positioned more in inconsistency than in a valid design decision.

[image]

In these cases, instead of creating different styles, the total color palette is usually established, with the corresponding adaptation to each used background:

[image]

A color adaptation while maintaining the same palette is much less relevant on a perceptual level than a change in style. Or, a slight perceptual change allows the logo to maintain the same corporate personality.

I would recommend studying all the colors in detail and establishing a base pattern regarding use. For example:

[image]

[image]